# How to save a spark dataframe in tableau format?

Tags: pyspark, tableau-api

Trying to save the spark dataframe(python) in .tde format. Will including these 4 jars in jars folder of spark will work?
jna.jar; tableauextract.jar; tableaucommon.jar; tableauserver.jar.If so how to get these jars?Could not find it on google search

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Pandas dataframe using the `.toPandas()` method available on any Spark dataframe.  From there, some options exist to get to a Tableau `.tde` file; check out this link:

`https://github.com/chinchon/python-tableau-tde`